# Test a factory of a 3rd party class

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice, mockito, factory

My application uses a third party jar (no access to source, etc.) I have a factory that creates an object (call it `Foo`) correctly from settings, i.e.

```
public FooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory {
    private final Settings settings;
    private final OtherDependency other;

    @Inject
    public FooFactoryImpl(Settings settings, OtherDependency other) {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.other = other;
    }

    public Foo create(String theirArg) {
        Foo newFoo = new Foo(theirArg); // there is no no-arg constructor

        // This isn't exactly the way I do it but this is shorter and close enough
        newFoo.setParamOne(settings.get("ParamOne")); 
        newFoo.setParamTwo(settings.get("ParamTwo"));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test this factory using Mockito - make sure the created object is configured correctly. But of course, I run into [this problem](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/); that is, because my factory calls `new`, I can't inject a spy.

One possible solution is to introduce something like:

```
public FooFactoryDumb implements FooFactory {
    public Foo create(String theirArg) {
        return new Foo(theirArg);
    }
}
```

And then something like:

```
public FooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory {
    @Inject @Dumb private FooFactory inner;

    // snip, see above

    public create(String theirArg) {
        Foo newFoo = inner.create(theirArg);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

This seems like a lot of boilerplate code just to enable unit testing. It [smells bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me, but I might be wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I had to use PowerMock anyway because the third party's methods were final. Since I'm already using PowerMock, I realized I can just do this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Foo toReturn = PowerMockito.mock(Foo.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(toReturn);
}
```

And then I don't have to touch my original class at all.

**Note:** If you do this, you have to prepare both classes for PowerMock, i.e. do

```
@PrepareForTest( { Foo.class, FooFactoryImpl.class } )
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar but simpler way to do it: add a protected method to your factory to create a Foo:

```
protected Foo create(String theirArg){
    return new Foo(theirArg);
}
```

then in your tests of your Factory, create a [Test Double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) of your FactoryImpl and override the create method:

```
private class FooFactoryImplTestDouble extends FooFactoryImpl{
    ...
    @Override
    protected Foo create(String theirArg){

        //create and return your spy here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely simpler. I guess I have dependency injection on the brain too much :) Going to see if there are other good answers before I accept.

Comment: I did this and it worked. And I didn't have to change my module or create annotations.

Comment: This is quite a reasonable idea if refactoring the factory is an option.  You don't need the Test Double class though; you can just use a Mockito spy of `FooFactoryImpl` and override the create method.  This should make your intentions clearer in your test code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class:

```
public class FooFactory3rd {
    public Foo create3rdParty(String theirArg) {
        return new Foo(theirArg);
    }
}
```

Then change your class to:

```
public FooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory {
    private final Settings settings;
    private final OtherDependency other;
    private final FooFactory3rd fooFactory3rd;

    @Inject
    public FooFactoryImpl(Settings settings, OtherDependency other, FooFactory3rd fooFactory3rd) {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.other = other;
        this.fooFactory3rd = fooFactory3rd;
    }

    public Foo create(String theirArg) {
        Foo newFoo = fooFactory3rd.create3rdParty(theirArg);

        // This isn't exactly the way I do it but this is shorter and close enough
        newFoo.setParamOne(settings.get("ParamOne")); 
        newFoo.setParamTwo(settings.get("ParamTwo"));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

And in your test code:

```
Foo fooMock = mock(Foo.class);
FooFactory3rd fooFactory3rdMock = mock(FooFactory3rd.class);
when(fooFactory3rdMock.create3rdParty(any(String.class)).thenReturn(fooMock);

FooFactoryImpl fooFactoryImpl = new FooFactoryImpl(settings, other, fooFactory3rdMock);
fooFactoryImpl.create("any string");
```

This way, you can inject your fooMock. When you call `fooFactoryImpl.create("any string")`, your mocked Foo is called under the cover.

Or if you want to go further clean, don't even need the constructor arg of FooFactory3rd. Just declare

```
    private final FooFactory3rd fooFactory3rd = new FooFactory3rd();
```

And in your test, use reflection to change it to the mocked FooFactory3rd.

Comment: I don't want to inject a mock, I want to inject a **spy**, I want to make sure the Factory called the correct set methods, and so forth. Additionally, to verify that a "workable, stateful and complete" object of Foo is created depends on a lot more things, including the output of get methods that I don't control, and so forth.

Comment: I see the point. However, unit testing is, like its name suggests, testing a unit of code. If the Foo foo = new Foo(arg) is part of your create method. You have to test it rather than inject a mock. One potential problem is that the new itself could fail, using a mock simply means you are just testing part of the "create" method. Once again, if the new is part of your unit, your unit test should test it as it is.

Comment: But `FooFactoryImpl` is the Class Under Test. I don't want to have to rely on the behavior of a third party class (`Foo`) to verify whether the class I wrote works.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. See the revised answer.

Comment: How is that an improvement over the answer in my post? It looks the same to me, except your version *doesn't* use Guice

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and think about what the contract of `FooFactoryImpl` is.  It is that it must create a fully functional `Foo`, whatever that means.  So if the contract of a `Foo` is that it does X, Y and Z, then the contract of a `FooFactoryImpl` is that it creates objects that do X, Y and Z.

This is a case for the kind of test in which the SUT consists of more than one class.  I don't care whether you call this a unit test, an integration test, a subsystem test, a collaboration test, or some other name.  The point is that the only meaningful test of `FooFactoryImpl` is a test that tests `Foo` as well.  Instead of writing a test class for `Foo` alone, write a test class that tests the two classes jointly.

So, if the contract of `Foo` is to do X, Y and Z, then your test cases will do the following things with a `FooFactoryImpl`.

- Call `create` and test that the created object does X.
- Call `create` and test that the created object does Y.
- Call `create` and test that the created object does Z.

I believe this is the only sensible way to attack this problem.  The hard part is coming up with a convincing name for the test class.

Comment: In the real world scenario, here `Foo` is more akin to a database layer or a web server than to a small object that does three or four tasks - and has the related resource dependencies. Imagine that it's a database connection, and one of the factory methods is `setPassword`; I cannot call `getPassword`. Nor does it make sense to see if I made a legal connection to the database in a unit test, where the database doesn't exist! To test the created object based on it's behavior is much more "integration test" than I want. And it also expects that the library has no bugs, which is not good either.